# "there were enough room" or "there was enough room"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, construction, there-is

Which is the correct verb, should it be singular or plural?

- 1.) *"There* ***were*** *enough room."*

or

- 2.) *"There* ***was*** *enough room."*

Comment: This is actually a good question, and it will probably get better answers here on EL&U, imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more appropriate to use "There was enough room" by treating the reference to 'room' as being singular. While 'room' may be in reference to an unbounded space and imply the need to treat it as plural, in this context it would be reasonable to treat it as one collectively, all-encompassing space.

Answer (score 2):

Room, when it means space, is an uncountable noun so will always be treated as a singular. There was enough room.

Room, when it means a space enclosed by walls, is a countable noun: There were enough rooms.